# Display of Pokémon comes with a delay

Tags: pokemon-go

Whenever I'm playing Pokémon Go, I cant seem to find any Pokémon. It seems to be because of some delay. I often can only catch Pokémon when I'm standing still and wait for the Pokémon to show up (if there are any).

When I'm walking with friends, they find many Pokémon, but I need to wait for roughly 2 minutes before the same Pokémon show up on my map.

When I minimize the Pokémon app by pressing the 'Recent apps button' and push the Pokémon tab, it will (I think) re-establish the app and the Pokémon will show up.

It looks like my Samsung S6 does not collect data all the time for the game, but only after some minutes. I think that's the reason why I need to wait for Pokémon to show up.

I have the same ISP as my friends and same phone.

Does anyone have any solution for me?

Comment: Do you have allow data, camera, contacts, etc enabled? Do you have GPS location on highest? Sometimes you have to reset the app to restablish a better connection

Comment: @Kiwi I do have them all enabled. I've also GPS location on highest. I even downloaded the Map of my city with Google Maps for a even better performance. I also reinstalled the pokemon go app.

Comment: Is two minutes an accurate account of the time or is it an exaggeration? it's common for Pokemon to show up ~30 seconds sooner for either myself or my husband when we play together. How much have you played? I've had multiple occasions where I was in an area for a minute or two with nothing, and then suddenly four Pokemon appeared. The servers are unstable, so if you have not played a lot, you may just be unlucky. My only thought not covered by Kiwi for causes is if you are holding the phone differently and it's getting a bad connection. Do you hold your phone the same way as your friends?

Comment: Thx for the Response Kat. I'm playing pokemon go like every day :/ you mentioned that it's common for pokemon to show up ~30 sooner, maybe I'm just being unlucky. I do think that's the case tho. I've never encountered a pokemon while cycling for instance, but my friends find them all the time while cycling (even when I'm alone cycling). It seems like I experience some lag/delay and when my mobile finds a pokemon, I'm already away from that spot. I'm just holding my phone straight in my hand, like everyone else :/

Comment: That does sound like an abnormal delay. Next time you play with your friends, compare your connection signals. Knowing whether your connection is worse or not would narrow it down.  Also try turning off WiFi; sometimes it will connect to a network with a weak signal and cause all sorts of issues. This seems unlikely if you are having the problem everywhere you go, though.

Answer (score 1):

On August 1st you would have been experiencing slowness from an API change Niantic made to begin preventing access from external sites.

There was a significant delay for any communication involving GPS, which includes Pokemon appearing in your field of view.

After Niantic fully blocked everything a couple days ago, you should be seeing significantly improved performance....although a severe lack of any means to track the Pokemon nearby :(

Comment: This doesn't explain why OP has the problem and not their friends, though.

Comment: Kat is right. Thx for the info tho.